# How to search for a maven dependency automatically in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I come from .NET world and in Visual Studio the search for dependencies from nuget is automatic. You can type part of the name in the Nuget Packet Manager and it will search for you all related packages, then you double click on it and you are done. I'm on a Java project now and I'm having to manually type the Maven dependency on the pom.xml after searching for it on the internet. Does eclipse have a similar way to search for dependencies as in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  If you have the M2E plugin properly installed, you will see that when you're editing the pom.xml, there are several tabs at the bottom of view, with "pom.xml" selected by default.

Click on the "Dependencies" tab, then the "Add.." button.

In the field that gets the focus, labeled "Enter groupId, ...", enter a substring of what you're looking for, be it a groupId or artifactId (the label has more hints about the format). If you wait a few moments after entering the string, whatever maven repositories you connect to would have responded with potential matches, which you can then select and confirm to add to the pom.xml.